# Gnome + KDE - SSH connection errors

Tags: gnome, ssh, kde

I have Ubuntu installed 19.10. Setup my ssh and can connect to our repository.
Today I installed kubuntu-desktop package and restarted and logged in to KDE.

There I cannot acces our repository. I am getting publick key denied error and the "-v" parameter says that the host is not know.

If I log out and log in to Gnome it is working like a charm.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: just to clarify. you are referring to the desktop environment of the client, and you are using a terminal to access ssh and you are logged in as the same user in KDE or Gnome?

Comment: Yes. So primarily I installed the flavor Ubuntu. Within this one I installed via apt the kubuntu-desktop.
I have Tilix installed with ZSH and with the same user I try to do e.g. a "git pull".
In Gnome it is workin.
In KDE i am getting "Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 1):

Okay found the solution.

The ssh-agent wasn'T aware of the keys. I wonder why. So reading here: 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/26505980/…

I did: 
`ssh-add <path-to_key>`

Then I could issue the git commands.